# Merge [comment] and [comments] tags

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

[comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comments) 2
[comment](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comment) 6

Answer (score 3):

Done.

I've changed `comment` to `comments` as in all cases the plural seemed a better tag.

There was even one question tagged both `comment` and `comments`.

I've also set up the `comment` -> `comments` synonym.